# WPF Control files are opening as Text Files on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml, syntax-highlighting

Though other types of files open fine and Auto completion is working, but Usercontrol(XAML files) appear as plain text with no syntax highlighting.

I went to the Text Editor section under Tools->Options and, whenever I tried to bring up the Formatting options for XAML, it says an error occurred.

It was working fine, but I had to uninstall/reinstall VS 2008 for some other issue and it's not working now.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling VS 2008, but the problem persists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using "devenv /resetsettings" or "devenv /ResetSkipPkgs" ?

I remember having similar issue a long time ago, and was able to fix it by using some command-line reset of the IDE.

Comment: God Bless you :). That did the Job. But day by day, I am starting to hate MS Products :(.